# How do I store a linked list's head node's address in a file and retrieve it later

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

Here is the code :

```
//Program to store memory address in a file & retrieve it later
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct employee {
    int empId;
    struct employee *next;
}emp;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    emp *node = NULL;
    FILE *fp;
    if (atoi(argv[1])==1) {
        node = (emp *) malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("Enter the employee Id: ");
        scanf("%d",&node->empId);
        node->next=NULL;
        printf("The value that was entered was: %d\n",node->empId);
        fp =  fopen("/home/userName/sampleAddress.txt","w");
        fprintf(fp,"%d",node);
        fclose(fp);
        node = NULL;
    }
    if (atoi(argv[1]) == 2) {
        fp = fopen("/home/userName/sampleAddress.txt","r");
        long address;
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &address);
        printf("address read: %d\n", address);
        memcpy(node, (const void *)address, sizeof(node));
        fclose(fp);
        printf("The empId is - %d\n",node->empId);
        free(node);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to store the address of node in a file. The next time I run the code with an argument '2', node should point to the memory address stored in the file.
I get a segmentation fault. Is this even possible; if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: On whatever your purpose is, you may want to dump the linked list to a file and load it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "The next time I run the code with an argument '2', node should point
>   to the memory address stored in the file."

The next time you run the code, any memory addresses previously in use will no longer be valid, and should not be used.

To be clear, the memory addresses in use in one process are not accessible in another process (unless some special shared mechanism is being used, and then marshalling occurs). Most (if not all) operating systems have some form of shared memory mechanism.

[What you should perhaps be doing is storing the node's content values in the file and then reading those back into a node.]

Comment: I am not freeing that memory. Is there no way for me to access it?

Comment: No. After the program has run, regardless of free()! You should probably read a tutorial on how memory is allocated and from where.

Comment: All memory that is associated with your program is freed when it closes.

Comment: Is there no way to access memory outside of my program's?

Comment: That would depend on the OS; many have shared memory of one form or another.

Comment: Yeah, I know that storing the contents into a file & reading the same is obviously the more sensible thing to do. But, I am still curious.

Answer (score 0):

The address you got for the "node" is only valid in that process.
When it is finished(for the first time) and you run it again with argument 2, it is completely a new process, the address space is totally different.
Thus this way is never going to work.

Comment: Yes, basically the same...I was trying to use my way to answer the question